# C - Separate Chaining Hash Table - Output and Space Issues

Tags: c, data-structures, malloc, hashtable, space-complexity

so basically I wrote a program to initialize, insert, and output the whole hash table. I thought I did pretty good, but there's many issues.

First issue being, some names are displayed with an additional weird character, why??

Second issue being, I can only input a size parameter (for initialize(size) function) of <8. Anything above 7 will output "Out of Space!" but why?? I thought I managed the space pretty well from what I was taught at uni:((

Please help!

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct list_node *node_ptr;

struct list_node
{
    node_ptr next;
    char *key;
    char *value;
    
};

typedef node_ptr LIST;
typedef node_ptr position;

struct hash_table
{
    LIST *list_ptr_arr;
    unsigned int table_size;
};

typedef struct hash_table *HASHTABLE;

unsigned long long int
hash(const char *key, unsigned int hash_size)
{

    unsigned long long int hash;

    for(int i = 0; key[i]; i++)
    {
        hash = (hash<<32)+key[i];
    }

    return (hash%hash_size);

}

unsigned int 
next_prime(int number)
{

    int j;

    for(int i = number; ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 2; j<i; j++)
        {
            if(i%j == 0){break;}
        }

        if(i==j){return j;}
    }
}

HASHTABLE
initialize(unsigned int table_size)
{
    HASHTABLE H;

    H = (HASHTABLE) malloc(sizeof(struct hash_table));
    if(H==NULL){printf("Out of Space!"); return 0;}

    H->table_size = next_prime(table_size);

    H->list_ptr_arr = (position*) malloc(sizeof(LIST)*H->table_size);
    if(H->list_ptr_arr==NULL){printf("Out of Space!"); return 0;}

    H->list_ptr_arr = (LIST*) malloc(sizeof(struct list_node)*H->table_size);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<H->table_size; i++)
    {
        if(H->list_ptr_arr[i]==NULL){printf("Out of Space!"); return 0;}

        H->list_ptr_arr[i]=NULL;
    }


    return H;
    
}

position
set(const char *key, const char *value)
{
    position entry = (position) malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
    entry->value = (char*) malloc(strlen(value)+1);
    entry->key = (char*) malloc(strlen(key)+1);
    strncpy(entry->key,key,strlen(key));
    strncpy(entry->value,value,strlen(value));
    entry->next = NULL;

    return entry;
}

void
insert(const char *key, const char *value, HASHTABLE H)
{
    unsigned int slot = hash(key, H->table_size);
    node_ptr entry = H->list_ptr_arr[slot];

    node_ptr prev;

    if(entry==NULL)
    {
        
        H->list_ptr_arr[slot] = set(key, value);
        return;
    }

    while(entry!=NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(entry->key, key)==0)
        {
            free(entry->value);
            entry->value = malloc(strlen(value)+1);
            strncpy(entry->value,value,strlen(value));
            return;
        }

        prev = entry;
        entry = prev->next;

    }

    
    prev->next = set(key, value);

}

void
dump(HASHTABLE H)
{

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<H->table_size; i++)
    {
        position entry = H->list_ptr_arr[i];

        if(H->list_ptr_arr[i]==NULL){continue;}

        printf("slot[%d]: ", i);

        for(;;)
        {
            printf("%s|%s -> ", entry->key, entry->value);

            if(entry->next == NULL)
            {
                printf("NULL");
                break;
            }

            entry = entry->next;
        }

        printf("\n");

    }

}


int main()
{
    
    HASHTABLE H = initialize(7);
    insert("name1", "David", H);
    insert("name2", "Lara", H);
    insert("name3", "Slavka", H);
    insert("name4", "Ivo", H);
    insert("name5", "Radka", H);
    insert("name6", "Kvetka", H);
    dump(H);
  
    return 0;   
    
}
```

Then I tried to change it up a bit:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct list_node *node_ptr;

struct list_node
{
    node_ptr next;
    char *key;
    char *value;
    
};

typedef node_ptr LIST;
typedef node_ptr position;

struct hash_table
{
    LIST *list_ptr_arr;
    unsigned int table_size;
};

typedef struct hash_table *HASHTABLE;

unsigned long long int
hash(const char *key, unsigned int hash_size)
{

    unsigned long long int hash;

    for(int i = 0; key[i]; i++)
    {
        hash = (hash<<32)+key[i];
    }

    return (hash%hash_size);

}

unsigned int 
next_prime(int number)
{

    int j;

    for(int i = number; ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 2; j<i; j++)
        {
            if(i%j == 0){break;}
        }

        if(i==j){return j;}
    }
}

HASHTABLE
initialize(unsigned int table_size)
{
    HASHTABLE H;

    H = (HASHTABLE) malloc(sizeof(struct hash_table));
    if(H==NULL){printf("Out of Space!1"); return 0;}

    H->table_size = next_prime(table_size);

    H->list_ptr_arr = (position*) malloc(sizeof(LIST)*H->table_size);
    if(H->list_ptr_arr==NULL){printf("Out of Space!2"); return 0;}

    H->list_ptr_arr = (LIST*) malloc(sizeof(struct list_node)*H->table_size);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<H->table_size; ++i)
    {
        if(H->list_ptr_arr[i]==NULL){printf("Out of Space!3"); return 0;}

        H->list_ptr_arr[i]->value="HEAD";
        H->list_ptr_arr[i]->next=NULL;
    }


    return H;
    
}


void
insert(const char *key, const char *value, HASHTABLE H)
{
    unsigned int slot = hash(key, H->table_size);
    LIST entry = H->list_ptr_arr[slot], newNode;



   

    newNode = (position) malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
    if(newNode==NULL){printf("Out of Space4!"); return;}
    newNode->next = entry->next;
    strncpy(newNode->key,key,strlen(key));
    strncpy(newNode->value,value,strlen(value));
    entry->next = newNode;

}

void
dump(HASHTABLE H)
{

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<H->table_size; i++)
    {
        position entry = H->list_ptr_arr[i];
        position p = entry->next;

        if(p==NULL){continue;}

        printf("slot[%d]: ", i);

        for(;;)
        {
            printf("%s|%s -> ", p->key, p->value);

            if(p->next == NULL)
            {
                printf("NULL");
                break;
            }

            p = p->next;
        }

        printf("\n");

    }

}


int main()
{
    
    HASHTABLE H = initialize(4);
    insert("name1", "David", H);
    insert("name2", "Lara", H);
    insert("name3", "Slavka", H);
    insert("name4", "Ivo", H);
    insert("name5", "Radka", H);
    insert("name6", "Kvetka", H);
    dump(H);
  
    return 0;   
    
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please post only one version of the code.

Comment: `H->list_ptr_arr = (position*) malloc(sizeof(LIST)*H->table_size);  H->list_ptr_arr = (LIST*) malloc(sizeof(struct list_node)*H->table_size);` That looks wrong. Both `malloc` results are bring assigned to the same pointer. I  think the second one should be a `for` that assigned `malloc` result to each array entry.

Comment: applicable for both versions no need to cast return of `malloc`

Comment: You posted the exact same code in another question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031109/c-making-a-separate-chaining-hash-table-issue and I pointed out some of the problems there. You are probably getting what you interpret as an allocation error because you test uninitialised memory and interpret NULL there as an allocation error. It isn't. It is not the only problem, but see my reply to the other question. You probably want to fix the issues there before you continue with the code because you will keep getting weird errors until you do.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the second piece of code, it runs correctly on my computer.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 256

// typedefing struct list_node multiple times is confusing, so I remove these typedefs
struct list_node {
    struct list_node *next;
    // strings need storage space in the memory,
    // declaring key and value as array here can save some calls to malloc()
    char key[MAX_SIZE];
    char value[MAX_SIZE];
};

struct hash_table {
    struct list_node **list_ptr_arr;
    unsigned int table_size;
};

// it's better not to hide pointer type using typedef
typedef struct hash_table HASHTABLE;

unsigned long long int hash(const char *key, unsigned int hash_size) {
    // hash is not initialized originally (the value is choosed randomly)
    unsigned long long int hash = 5;

    for (int i = 0; key[i]; i++) {
        hash = (hash << 32) + key[i];
    }

    return (hash%hash_size);
}

unsigned int next_prime(int number) {
    int j;

    for (int i = number; ; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i%j == 0) { break; }
        }

        if (i == j) { return j; }
    }
}

HASHTABLE *initialize(unsigned int table_size) {
    HASHTABLE *H;

    // you don't need to type cast malloc() result in C
    H = malloc(sizeof(*H));

    H->table_size = next_prime(table_size);
    
    // I suppose list_ptr_arr is a pointer to an array of struct list_node * object
    H->list_ptr_arr = malloc(sizeof(*(H->list_ptr_arr)) * H->table_size);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < H->table_size; ++i) {
        // malloc() for H->list_ptr_arr only allocated area for struct list_node * array, the struct list_node pointed to is not allocated yet, so malloc() here
        H->list_ptr_arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(*(H->list_ptr_arr[i])));
        strcpy(H->list_ptr_arr[i]->value, "HEAD");
        H->list_ptr_arr[i]->next = NULL;
    }

    return H;
}


void insert(const char *key, const char *value, HASHTABLE *H) {
    unsigned int slot = hash(key, H->table_size);
    struct list_node *entry = H->list_ptr_arr[slot], *newNode;

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));

    newNode->next = entry->next;
    // strlen() doesn't count the '\0', just use strcpy here
    strcpy(newNode->key, key);
    strcpy(newNode->value, value);
    entry->next = newNode;
}

void dump(HASHTABLE *H) {

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < H->table_size; i++) {
        struct list_node *entry = H->list_ptr_arr[i];
        struct list_node *p = entry->next;

        if (p == NULL) { continue; }

        printf("slot[%d]: ", i);

        for (;;) {
            printf("%s|%s -> ", p->key, p->value);

            if (p->next == NULL) {
                printf("NULL");
                break;
            }

            p = p->next;
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main() {

    HASHTABLE *H = initialize(4);
    insert("name1", "David", H);
    insert("name2", "Lara", H);
    insert("name3", "Slavka", H);
    insert("name4", "Ivo", H);
    insert("name5", "Radka", H);
    insert("name6", "Kvetka", H);
    dump(H);

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Don't forget to free the hashtable.